# Get value of same column from next row if current column value is null

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table and I want to select one column such as if it's record not found(cause I have joins with other tables) or exists but is null than select value of same column from next row. I tried to use isnull and coalesce functions but I am unable to get value of next row.
Any help or link would be appreciated.

Here is my query so far

```
Select 
  (select top 1 OpenPrice from #tbltempData where Dated=D.Dated) [Open],
  ISNULL((select top 1 ClosePrice from #tbltempData where Dated= DATEADD(hour,@Interval-1, D.Dated)),
  (select top 1 ClosePrice from #tbltempData where Dated= DATEADD(hour,0, D.Dated))) [Close], 
  [Min],[Max],Dated
from #tbltempData2 D
Order BY Dated Asc
```

Open column is having null values.

here is Screenshot of my sample data[image]

and here is output am getting
[image]

Details: as I have records in my sample data for date '28/06/2019' and time for first record is 9 am and I am grouping my data in 2 hours so after grouping my first group record of same date is for 8am and as I have no value for that time in sample data so am getting null values. to avoid this scenario I want to get OpenPrice value where time is 9am(in sample data) of same date cause that time is in same group.

Comment: What database is it? oracle? sql server

Comment: sql server database

Comment: someone can explain why am getting negative vote?

Comment: how do you define "next row"? How do you select it?

Comment: @EricZ that's the question. e.g right now it's showing top record from OpenPrice column and according to my condition Openprice doest not exist for one time so it show null and I want to show value of OpenPrice from next record where it is not null.

Comment: @AneeqAzamKhan  The problem is we don't know your data, and can not know what is "next record".  Please share sample data and expected output, so people could understand better

Comment: @EricZ I have edited my question please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want "next row" always greater than current time

```
[Open] = (
       select top 1 OpenPrice 
       from #tbltempData t 
       where DATEDIFF(day,t.Dated,D.Dated) = 0   -- make sure the price for same day
         AND t.Dated>=D.Dated 
       ORDER BY t.Dated ASC
)
```

In case you want "next row" be closest available time slot

```
 [Open] = (
       select top 1 OpenPrice 
       from #tbltempData t 
       where DATEDIFF(day,t.Dated,D.Dated) = 0   -- make sure the price for same day
       ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(minute,t.Dated,D.Dated)) ASC
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a correlated subquery does what you want:

```
select d.*,
       (select top (1) ClosePrice
        from #tbltempData td
        where td.Dated <= D.Dated
        order by td.Dated desc
       ) as ClosePrice
from #tbltempData2 d
order by dated Asc
```

Comment: this solution has removed null but value is not from sample data there is difference in points.